# Can I safely delete /var/log/messages-20210328 which is 383M under / directory ? OS version:Oracle Linux Server 6.7. db version Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, linux

the content of file is displayed using

```bash
# cat /var/log/messages-20210328
```

Output:

```
Mar 21 04:31:11 testdb snmpd[17566]: Connection from UDP: [*.*.*.274]:61775->[*.*.*.*]
Mar 21 04:31:11 testdb snmpd[17566]: Connection from UDP: [*.*.*.274]:61787->[*.*.*.*]
Mar 21 04:31:11 testdb snmpd[17566]: truncating integer value > 32 bits
...
```

Comment: Judging by the filename, which includes a date indicating when it was rolled over from the active /var/log/messages, this is no longer being written to by the system. If you don't need the content for anything yourself, then you can delete it.

Comment: @pmdba Thanks! I just deleted such kind of files with rm command, because I do not need the content of it.

Comment: In general you can, however have a look at [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate), then you don't have to do it by hand.

Comment: /var/log/messages and its archives probably don't contain anything regarding the database.